# When I connect the emulator with filters, it does not recognize the emulator's path

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

When I connect the emulator with filters on Android Studio, it does not recognize the emulator's path and brings me this error:

```
Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)
INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR | is an experimental feature.
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.88.I have tried all available methods but no results
```

I re-downloaded the sdk manager and redefined the emulator's path and re-downloaded Android Studio but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates, that you're running multiple emulators with the same AVD (Android Virtual Device).
This could either be you actually running multiple emulators.
In that case you should provide the `-read-only` flag as stated by the error messages.

Alternatively, you might have leftover lock files in your .android folder.
In that case, you can simply remove them using
`rm ~/.android/avd/**/*.lock`

You can also stop the AVDs in Tools -> AVD Manager